# how to hide a partition with active VHD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, partitioning

i'm trying to create a partition where it'd store an image of the OS with all the necessary software installed(i still need to find out how to do it) and an active VHD attached

something like this

+----------------------+--------------------+
| VHD file + image | SYSTEM (8.1)    |
+----------------------+--------------------+
　　|
+-------+
| VHD     |
+-------+
where the image and the VHD file would be hidden to the user so that they wouldn't be able to accidentally delete them

is there a way to do it?

it would cretaintly seem easy to just remove the partition path, and it'd be inaccessible, but upon reboot, the VHD drive would disappear

Comment: indeed, i've read this before i've posted this post, but i just want to create a hidden partition, no page files or those kinda stuff

Comment: If by hidden, you mean without a drive letter, and it doesn't have page or boot files you can simply remove the drive letter. If that's what you mean and it does have those files, you need to follow the above post. If you want to "hide" them such that they won't be visible in disk management from the guest, I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: oh, that's the first thing i've tried, but when i remove the path to the partition with VHD, upon rebooting, the VHD would be inaccessible...    and that's the problem i'm trying to solve

Comment: I'm now confused. Do you want to hide it or make it accessible?

Comment: i just lost my computer trying to solve my problem, and the account was a temporary one, but i'm the poster. i would like to hide the partition which contains the vhd and the image, so when the user is using the VHD as their storage medium, they don't accidentally delete the VHD file

Comment: If you [register an account](https://superuser.com/users/signup) you will be able to request that your old and new accounts are merged by using the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and selecting "I need to merge accounts in the drop down. This will allow you comment on, edit and accept answer to this question, and is necessary if you want to be able to use the site effectively across multiple computers.